# Nagios Plugin for reading RMON files

Tags: nagios, nrpe

May I know if Nagios is able read and display information from `.rmon` and `.pmon` files  ?

Samples:

**.rmon**

```
Time Stamp,RX Octs,TX Octs,RX Pkts,TX Pkts,RX Drop Events,Status,RX Undersize Pkts,Status,RX Fragments,Status,RX 64Octs,TX 64Octs,RX 65 to 127Octs,TX 65 to 127Octs,RX 128 to 255Octs,TX 128 to 255Octs,RX 256 to 511Octs,TX 256 to 511Octs,RX 512 to 1023Octs,TX 512 to 1023Octs,RX 1024 to 1518Octs,TX 1024 to 1518Octs,RX CRC Alignment Errors,Status,RX Oversize Pkts,Status,TX Oversize Pkts,RX Jabbers,RX Multicast Pkts,TX Multicast Pkts,RX Broadcast Pkts,TX Broadcast Pkts,TX Collisions,Status,RX Unknown TPID,RX Unknown VID,RX MAC Limit,RX Filter Discard,RX QoS Discard,TX Queue0 Discard,TX Queue1 Discard,TX Queue2 Discard,TX Queue3 Discard,TX Queue4 Discard,TX Queue5 Discard,TX Queue6 Discard,TX Queue7 Discard,Record Status
00:15,69586578,421339463,525456,1172251,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,54916,153676,306346,354260,142676,60877,15165,87807,6265,515626,88,5,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,0,0,1798,0,14,0,NORMAL,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,MAINT
00:30,54931226,290982247,425662,873843,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,49302,135761,249862,279097,113025,44823,6999,71647,6340,342510,125,5,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,0,0,1782,0,16,0,NORMAL,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,MAINT
```

**.pmon**

```
Time Stamp,RF BBE,Status,RF ES,Status,RF SES,Status,RF SEP,Status,RF UAS,Status,RF OFS,Status,RX Level (MAX) [dBm],Status,RX Level (MIN) [dBm],Status,Record Status
00:15,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,-30.2,NORMAL,-31.4,NORMAL,VALID
00:30,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,-30.2,NORMAL,-30.7,NORMAL,VALID
00:45,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,0,NORMAL,-30.3,NORMAL,-31.2,NORMAL,VALID
```

**UPDATE**

I am thinking of using NRPE to run a bash script which extract or parse information from the files. Then display the information on the monitoring server. Is there a way display the information in graph format ?

Comment: Cacti or observium should be more oriented to display usage graphs than Nagios

Comment: How do I use it to read the `rmon` files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write script to check those files. In that script you need to output the values you want to be graphed as performance data. 
I suggest you to read the plugin development guidelines https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html.

You can perform the check with NRPE or alternatively via SSH using check_by_ssh plugin or check_by_ssh_master plugin https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/%2A-Remote-Check-Tunneling/check_by_ssh_master/details.

For viewing the graphs you will need pnp4nagios https://docs.pnp4nagios.org/.